# type mismatch elastic search

Tags: scala, elasticsearch

getting this error let me know how to fix this. According the link https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s response should be SearchResponse.

build sbt is as below:

```
 libraryDependencies += "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" % "elastic4s-core_2.11" % "2.2.0"
```

code is below:

```
def searchItem(q: String): Future[SearchResponse] = {
  val productsIndex = ESConfig.productsIndex
  val rs = client.execute {
    search in productsIndex / "items" query q
  }
  rs
}
```

Error is as below:

```
[error] /home/shravan/Building_a_Recommendation_Engine_with_scala/src/main/scala/chapter07/ESUtil.scala:58: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[com.sksamuel.elastic4s.RichSearchResponse]
[error]  required: scala.concurrent.Future[org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse]
[error]     rs
[error]     ^
```

Answer (score 0):

In `elatic4s` *2.20*, it has build a new model `RichSearchResponse` to replace the original *elasticsearch* `SearchResponse` for easier operation in `Scala`, if you still need to get the original *elasticsearch* `SearchResponse`, You can do it like:

```
def searchItem(q: String): Future[RichSearchResponse] = {
  val productsIndex = ESConfig.productsIndex
  val rs = client.execute {
    search in productsIndex / "items" query q
  }
  rs
}
val s: SearchResponse = Await(searchItem("test"), Duration.Inf).original
```

or

```
def searchItem(q: String): Future[SearchResponse] = {
  val productsIndex = ESConfig.productsIndex
  val rs = client.execute {
    search in productsIndex / "items" query q
  }
  rs.map(s => s.original)
}
```